# why not have a virtual ptr per class?

Tags: c++, memory, polymorphism

It seems that it's sufficient to have a virtual ptr per class even when a class is derived from two base classes.

For example,

```
#include <iostream>
class A{
public:
    void* ptr;
    virtual void printNonOverride() {
        std::cout << "no override" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void print() {
        std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class C {
public:
    double c;
    virtual void cFunc() {
        std::cout << "C";
    }
};

class B : public A , public C {
};

int main() {
    A a{};
    std::cout << sizeof a << std::endl;
    C c{};
    std::cout << sizeof c << std::endl;
    B b{};
    std::cout << sizeof b << std::endl;
}
```

The output for this is

```
16
16
32
```

which makes sense because `sizeof B  = sizeof A + sizeof C`. However, this seems a little bit inefficient. Why does `B` need to allocate 2 virtual pointers? Why not just allocate one that refers to B's own virtual tables? Then the `sizeof B` will be `24`. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, now you pass a pointer to `B` to a function whose parameter is a pointer to `A`. Do you expect that this function can call `A`'s virtual method? Where would `A`'s virtual dispatch comes from, if that particular `A` does not have a virtual dispatch pointer? If you try to wrap your brain around this, you will actually reach a conclusion that `B`, overall, must have not just two, but three virtual pointers, somewhere inside it.

Comment: `B` can be referenced with `A* a = &b;` and `C* c = &b;`.

Comment: `A* pa = &b; C* pb = &b; cout << &b << " " << pa << " " << pb << "\n";` How would you reconcile the pointers to their respective objects and their virtual function table pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you can do

```
B b{};
C* pc = &b;

pc->cFunc();
```

and `pc` has to point to something that looks like a `C` - including starting with a virtual pointer suitable for a `C`.

`B` and `A` can share the same virtual pointer, because the compiler can make it so that `B`'s virtual table begins the same way as `A`'s virtual table (and then has some extra stuff at the end). But it can't do this for both `A` and `C` at the same time. `B`'s virtual table can't begin the same way as `A`'s *and* begin the same way as `C`'s. That's not possible.